# Use of the "solve" function takes too long

Tags: performance, matlab

I'm a beginner when it comes to using Matlab. I'm currently using the 7.12 version.

My problem is fairly simple. I need to solve an equation (in this case I need to find where myfun equals to 0):

```
myfun = @(tf) 2*pi/N+(ti-tf)*v_ang+A/(2*pi*f)*(cos(2*pi*f*tf)-cos(2*pi*f*ti));
```

As you can see the variable is tf, all others are constant.

I solve it using the following line (and use the solution to calculate a value that I store in the array *delta_t*):

```
delta_t(i) = (solve(myfun(t))-delta_t(i-1))*10^9;
```

But the thing is, I have to solve it a lot of times (more than half a million times actually), and as you can see the value of `delta_t(i)` depends on `delta_t(i-1)`.

So here's my problem : **how can I make the solving process faster ?** I have tried this line :

```
delta_t(i) = (solve(myfun(t),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints','true','MaxDegree','1')-delta_t(i-1))*10^9;
```

But it messes up my code and I get an error, plus I'm not really convinced it would make a great difference anyway.

On top of that, I noticed that the more I use *solve* the slower it gets. For instance, if there are 10 000 iterations, the solving at iteration number 9000 will be slower than the one at iteration 10.

I hope that I am clear, please excuse my English as it is not my native tongue.

PS: I have tried with `A=0`, it really is faster (about 10 times faster) but still it gets slower as the program runs.

Comment: Can you give the values of the parameters `N, ti, v_ang, ...` you used? Are you using the symbolic toolbox?

Comment: are you preallocating `delta_t`? That could be part of the issue.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering me !
I am indeed pre-allocating 'delta_t' with 'delta_t = zeros(nb,1);'. The thing is, on the first iteration 'ti' is 0 and then it's the previous 'tf'.
'N' is 48, 'v_ang' is 21, 'f' is 90

Comment: I switched to the "fzero" function, so far it seems to be about 10 times faster, which allows me to do work in reasonable time so I'm good. Thanks again guys !